# what is the best way to manage having a file sent from a Golang server to a React front after submitting a form?

Tags: excel, reactjs, http, go, server

The React front contains filters that allow to sort out users in the DB.
Based on these filters, after clicking a Submit button, the app should generate an .xlsx or .csv file, a download should pop up in the browser and be Saved as...

What would be the best way to proceed ?

Should I build it in order that Golang would send the file to React after generating the file?

Currently, the file creation functions are made in Golang. Should the creation be managed in the front instead ?

Well, I'm a bit confused about how proceed and what to use ...

Comment: There is no "best way" here. Which is best depends on your needs and goals.

Comment: But once you choose a method, if you need help implementing that, that would make for a good question.